# Prevent fs (SD card) from getting an item in Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, sd-card

Is there anyway I can prevent the following behavior (running Ubuntu 14.04)?

I keep an SD card plugged into my computer, and every time I boot it up or bring it back from suspension, it adds an item to the Unity launcher to open the SD card in Nautilus.

Worse, whenever I bring the computer out of suspension, it goes ahead in opening a Nautilus window for the SD card. (Actually, it's worse than this because I have multiple partitions on my SD card, and Ubuntu creates an individual Nautilus window and Unity launcher for each one. It takes up a lot of space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to block the autoopen behaviour I think can only be done globally. Any other disk inserted will also affected.

Please try,

1. Open terminal application
2. Then type the following, and hit enter.

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
   ```
3. If no error shown, then test the behaviour by reinsert your SD card

Reference : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971712

Note : I hope this setting point not changed on recent Ubuntu

**Update :**

After more research, actually, Ubuntu Unity provide a way to get rid certain device by blacklisting it. Here the *unprecise* guide (because I'm not Ubuntu user anymore)

1. Open terminal
2. Type in `sudo blkid` and there will show you output similar to below

   ```
   ...
   /dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="4848-E35A" TYPE="vfat" 
   ...
   ```

   If you don't have root priviledge, try `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` instead.
3. Look at your device (possibly `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`) and take a note on the `UUID='CODE_SERIES'` part
4. Then add the partition UUID to Unity blacklist, by issuing command below

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "CODE_SERIES"
   ```
5. Test it.

If command on step #5 fail, please download `dconf-editor` application to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Awesome! That takes care of the second behaviour! +1

Comment: Maybe you can try `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices devices-option "Never"` for the first, I doubt if it is what you need...

Comment: Thanks, but `devices-option` doesn't appear to be one of the available keys under `com.canonical.Unity.Devices` on my system. (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I'm sorry for giving the wrong key as I have put my Ubuntu down. But, I've update the answer. Hopefully, it's not wrong again.

Comment: It looks like the right setting is `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "['<uuid-label>']"`, but, oddly, this setting gets overwritten (reverting to its previous value) every time I bring the machine back from suspension.

Comment: If you log off then log in again will revert it? If yes, I think Unity itself who revert the value. Maybe an automated autostart script would help.

Comment: actually, logout+login does *not* revert it. My setting is preserved across the logout+login process, even without the command in my `.profile` file.